# Draw Complex shapes

Tags: openlayers-2, leaflet, google-maps-api

Is it possible to draw complex shapes (polygons) like below image, combining lines and arcs. It is more like a Land Survey plan. So I have coordinates of each point and in case of arc - Radius, Chord, length, coordinate ..

[image]

I have been trying to find possible solution, but couldn't find any. I am open to Google Maps API, Openlayers / OL 3, Leafletjs

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is no ready to use tool available, but I think it's not that difficult to implement you own tool by using any of the three library. For example in OpenLayers, I think you can create a DrawComplexShape control, it can be extend the general DrawFeature Control with draw arc capabilities.

The main challenge would be to draw arcs. In terms of that, there is a very good example [here](http://gis.ibbeck.de/ginfo/apps/OLExamples/OL29/Thaleskreis/thaleskreis.asp) for you to study. After implementing the method, you will need to design and implement the user interaction to input needed arguments to the method. It can be either just some text boxes where you can type in values or in a fancier way via mouse gestures (so you can view the results via mouse move).